# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement -- Spring ROO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, spring-roo

I'm Building and web App using the Spring Roo Tool. and while creating my classes via the roo shell console, I've used several times the option `-permitReservedWords` to create some classes (e.g. Role, Group and User).

After generating the CRUD Views, I get this exception :

> "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
>   statement"

Then I realized that the problem occurs only for entities with reserved Names, so How can I force these entities name, if it's not possible how can I edit the names, because the refactor option in eclipse doesn't solve the problem, especial with a lot of AspectJ Files in the projects ...

Comment: You cannot force the reserved names with most databases (these names are SQL keywords). Ask a separate question about refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the JPA default table name is the name of the class (minus the package) with the first letter capitalized, this is why you need `-permitReservedWords`. Your entities *User*, *Role*, etc by default will be stored in *User*, *Role*, etc tables that are reserved words in almost all databases.

To change the default behaviour, use the annotation "@Table(name="app_user")" (javax.persistence.Table) to specify/customize the database table name that stores the data of given Entity. For example, *User* entity could be stored in *uzer* table.

Comment: That's what I've done to solve this issue :) I'll accept your answer.